# How can i map multiple classes to one table in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

From my research, it seems not likely that it's possible, but here is my use case.

I have a table called user with an address id.

I'd like to map a UserReference and User class to this table where UserReference does not contain the Address object (to save sql joining time) and User *does* contain the Address object (in case it's needed).

I can't use *subclass* since it expects a join table, and I can't just define two separate classes because a get() seems to return double of every row (one for User, one for UserReference).

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

---

I guess I should try to explain myself better.

```
public class UserReference {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

public class User extends UserReference {
    private Address;
}
```

I'd like to map both UserReference and User so that I can query for UserReference when I only need the basic details, and User whenever I need the full object.

I understand that I can simply have Address be lazy loaded but I have a two tier system which unproxies all objects once it passes through the layers.

---

edit:

Perhaps my question was too ambiguous, but based on the answers, it doesn't seem very possible to do what I want. Thanks anyway everyone.

Comment: It is actually absolutely fine to have same table mapped to multiple entities.  However if you are solving your "unproxy" problem (I bet you mean you are navigating the whole object graph?) by such approach, you are going to be in deep trouble in the future, especially you have more complicated object relationships, and in different function you need different combination of relationships.

Comment: Hmm could you explain further why this may be a problem down the line?

Comment: for example, If you system continue to grow, you may have an entity A having relationship to B, C, D and E.  And you may have different functions that function 1 will need only A, function 2 will need A + B, function 3 will need A + C + D,  function 4 will need A + C + E etc.  By using your approach, you will need to have different forms of A entity to cope with use of different function.  That's going to be a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not very clear to me but I'll try to answer as per my understanding. It depends upon what you really want to persist and what you want as a java entity.

Consider you want to represent User class with a database table i.e. represent User as entity in JPA. Now you can Create an Embeddable class which will be part of another class.

So you can map an Address class in User Entity and make the Address class as Embeddable using [@Embeddable annotation](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/25/jpa-embeddable-annotation/)
package com.thejavageek.embeddabledemo;

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String area;
    private String city;
    private String pincode;

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

}
```

and you can embed this embeddable class as below

```
package com.thejavageek.embeddabledemo;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @TableGenerator(name = "person_gen", table = "id_gen", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_val", allocationSize = 100)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "person_gen")
    private String idperson;
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    public String getIdperson() {
        return idperson;
    }

    public void setIdperson(String idperson) {
        this.idperson = idperson;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

UserReference.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "UserReference")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class UserReference extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "User")
public class User extends UserReference {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

}
```

Comment: does the original poster really want inheritance ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is you have a table like

```
USER
- USER_ID
- USER_NAME
- ADDRESS_ID
```

and

```
ADDRESS
- ADDRESS_ID
- ADDRESS_DETAIL
```

something like that?

And you want to have 2 `User` entities, one of it contains reference to Address and another did not (so it save SQL join time, as you said), is my understanding correct?

If so, you do not need to do so.

Simply have one `User` entity and put its `Address` relationship to be LAZY fetched.

If in any function you need `Address` in your `User`, do a join fetch.

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;
}
```

in such case, all normal retrieval of `User` will not incur any join to `Address` table.  However it is flexible to do something like

```
from User u left join fetch u.address where u.name like 'blabala'
```

Comment: Lazy fetch would work except that I have a multi-tier system so one it passes the layers the Address object is expected to be fetched.

Comment: That's not going to be a problem.  I have been doing same thing for years. you have two choices: 1. Make sure that for functions that need address, you have fetched address (by join fetch etc) before you returning the object out of transaction boundary. Or, 2. Construct a non-persistent related value object before you return from the txn boundary. There are other ways like open session in view or using jpa impl that allow lazy fetch without active txn. I just don't like those way personally.