# Hibernate entity related to two other entities causes NPE when trying to query database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, entity-relationship

Apologies if there is an obvious problem, I'm new to Hibernate. I've spent the last 3 hours scouring the googles, it's very likely I'm not phrasing my question correctly. I think I might have a circular reference, but I'm not sure.

I have 3 entities. The relationships I am trying to materialize are:

1. An Institution can have many courses
2. An Institution can be a sponsor
3. A course can have many sponsors
4. A sponsor can have many courses

My unit test creates these entities, saves them, and then queries for them to make sure I can read & write to the DB correctly and maintain the relationships.

1. If I only add an institution (BMC) to a course, everything is fine.
2. If I only add sponsors (BMC, HKU) to a course, everything is fine.
3. If I add an institution (BMC) and sponsors (BMC) to a course, when I try to get the course back, I get an empty object, which ultimately causes an NPE

I'm representing the many-to-many relationship in the third entity, CourseDetails. Ultimately, the CourseDetails will have several many-to-many relationships. However, only institution is used in multiple places.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

** EDIT ** I can confirm that the data is being saved correctly in the database when I look at in Toad. The course table has the correct institution_id and the courseDetails_institution has the correct mapping of course_id and institution_id

**Institution**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "institution_id")
    @Column(name = "institution_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "sponsor")
    private boolean sponsor;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sponsors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<CourseDetails> courseDetails = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    protected Institution() {
        // no-op constructor for hibernate, cannot be private
    }

    public Institution(String name, String abbreviation) {
        super(name, abbreviation);
        this.sponsor = false;
    } 
// Setters, getters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity.
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "course_id")
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Institution institution;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<CourseDetails> courseDetails = new HashSet<>();
// Setters, getters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity.
```

**CourseDetails**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="courseDetails")
public class CourseDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "courseDetails_id")
    @Column(name = "courseDetails_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Institution> sponsors = new HashSet<>();
    // Setters, getters, equals, hashcode omitted for brevity.
```

**Relevant methods for querying**

```
public <T> List getAllEntities(final Class<T> clazz) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T>  criteria = builder.createQuery(clazz);
    Root<T> root = criteria.from(clazz);
    criteria.select(root);
    final Session session = startTransaction();
    List<T> results = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    endTransaction(session);
    return results;
}

public Session startTransaction() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    activeSessions.add(session);
    return session;
}

public void endTransaction(final Session session) {
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    activeSessions.remove(session);
}
```

Comment: Just to clear up, there is only one institution entity with a sponsor attribute or you want 2 entities institution and sponsor?

Comment: There is just the one institution entity with a sponsor flag.

Comment: This looks like a many-to-many mapping.  Have you seen this http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many?

Comment: I currently have it as many_sponsors to many_courses and one_institution to many_courses. Do you mean I should have a many_institution to many_courses?

Comment: Yes, or you can use map the institution into 2 entities: institution one to many, sponsor many to many. see this on how to map one table to 2 entities.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655306/how-can-i-map-multiple-classes-to-one-table-in-hibernate

Comment: I went with the mapping 2 classes to 1 table method and everything is now working as expected. Thank you so much! Out of curiosity, was I envisioning the data model incorrectly for Hibernate to understand? It seems like both the 2 classes to 1 table and using the 1 class multiple times should be equivalent.

Comment: Your data model implementation was "incorrect" as you can't enforce one-to-many relationship on the institution entity.  If both institution and sponsor have the same relationship requirement, you can use one entity.

Answer (score 0):

Jules' comments have answered my question. I needed to either have the institution be a many-to-many relationship or create two entities that map to the same table. This is what I ended up doing:

**BaseInstitution**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="institution")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula(
        "CASE WHEN sponsor " +
        "THEN 'SPONSOR' " +
        "ELSE 'INSTITUTION' " +
        "END "
)
public class BaseInstitution {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "institution_id")
    @Column(name = "institution_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "sponsor")
    private boolean sponsor = false;
```

**Sponsor**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SPONSOR")
public class Sponsor extends BaseInstitution {  
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sponsors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<CourseDetails> courseDetails = new HashSet<>();
```

**Institution**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INSTITUTION")
public class Institution extends BaseInstitution {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "course_id")
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Institution institution;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Set<CourseDetails> courseDetails = new HashSet<>();
```

**CourseDetails**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="courseDetails")
public class CourseDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "table-generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "table-generator", pkColumnValue = "courseDetails_id")
    @Column(name = "courseDetails_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    protected Set<Sponsor> sponsors = new HashSet<>();
```